# Difference between encrypted backup of an encrypted DB and an unencrypted backup of an encrypted DB

Tags: oracle, backup, security, encryption

Let's say we have a fully encrypted database (the type of encryption is not considered in this scenario), and we produce two backups for that database.

If I encrypt only one of the backups, would there be a difference between it and the other one? Is it redundant to encrypt the backup if the database was already encrypted?

I ask from the perspective of the security of the data, not performance or anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a tag for the DBMS you are asking about.

Comment: It is intended as a general not vendor-specific question, but if that information is necessary to answer it, let's say it is Oracle.

Comment: Probably vendor specific, but I assume there are things besides data in an encrypted database that is not encrypted (say routines as an example).

Answer (score 1):

[Does Rman Re-Encrypt TDE (Tablespace) Encrypted Data? (Doc ID 819167.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=819167.1)

(above link requires an account associated with a valid support contract)

> When using column encryption, these columns as well as other data in
>   the tables are encrypted again during the backup. If you are using
>   tablespace encryption these are not further encrypted during backups.

...

> ... for compressed backup on an encrypted tablespace, RMAN must decrypt
>   all the blocks, compress them, and encrypt them using RMAN encryption ...